# Tips to easy gameloop when dead

Tags: python-2.7, repeat

Im a beginner when it comes to Python, but i've manage to make a simple program where you die. The problem is to get the retry command right after you die. Sorry for all the comments in the code.

Here's the code:

```
import time

def repeat():   # create a new definition called repeat     
work_in_progress()      # starts work_in_progress def when called later in the program

def end():              # creates a new definition called end
quit()              # Does what it says. It quits the program when called. 

        # The program jumps over the next def becouse the def has not yet been called

prompt = '>'            # promt is sett as a string
def work_in_progress():             # Creates a new definition called work_in_progress
print "How many hours of work do you have?"
work = raw_input(prompt)            # work is sett as the users input
print "So you have %s hours of work?!?" % work          # uses the answer the user inputs

work_in_progress()          # The program calls the work_in_progress def. work_in_progress executes

print "does it continue?"

print "Let's make a death def"

def your_dead():            # Creates a new def named your_dead
print "You died during this program! Too bad..."
print "Try again?"
again = raw_input(prompt)               # Again is sett as prompt which has been given a string
if again == "yes":              # If the user answer yes in the last input
    work_in_progress()              # Execute work_in_progress
elif again == "no":             # If user answer no in the last input
    end()                           # End program
else:                   #If something else than yes or no are entered in the input
    print "%s is not a valid answer" % again                # print this
    your_dead()                 # Execute this

    # The next def is not called yet so it jumps over it.

def life_quest():           # Creates a new def called life_quest
print "Die or live?"
life = raw_input(prompt         # life is sett as a prompt which has been given a string
if life == "die":           # If user input in life is die
    your_dead()                 # Execute your_dead
elif life == "live":        # Else if user input in life is live
    print "Let's start again"       # Print this
    work_in_progress()          #Execute this
else:                   # User input is something else
    life_quest()            # Execute this

life_quest()        # life _quest is called and are executed
```

Comment: Your code formatting is messed up, making it real hard to read the code.

Comment: Specifically, you're mixing tabs and spaces. Bad idea.

Comment: How can i change it? What to do and not to do?